# If $A\unlhd B$, then prove that $A\phi\unlhd B\phi$ for a homomorphism $\phi$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism, and let $A $, $B$ be subgroups of $G$. If $A$ is normal subgroup of $B$, then prove that $A\phi$ is normal subgroup of $B\phi$

I saw this definiton in my notebook, but there was not any proof for it. Could you give me any hint, theorem or source to prove it?

I know that there must be "work" here. However, I could not think anything. Firstly, I thought that abelian groups can be used but I realized it won't work.

Thanks for every contribution.

Comment: You have to work with the definitions of normal subgroup and group homomorphism.

Comment: I cast the final undelete vote. It is rude to delete a question after someone has taken the time to answer it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4184313/104041 As Shaun shared earlier, this is a duplicate posted very recently: for those who can see it.

Comment: So Shaun worked to have the earlier post he didn't answer, of which this was one was a duplicate, closed and deleted, he could have this later post, which he answered prior to closure and deletion, fully restored.

Comment: This *is* the earlier post, @amWhy.

Answer (score 1):

To show $A\phi\le B\phi$, use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

Since $A\le G$, we have $e\in A$ and so $e\phi\in A\phi$. Thus $A\phi\neq\varnothing$.

Let $a\phi\in A\phi$, $a\in A$. Then, since $A\unlhd B$, we have $a\in B$, so $a\phi\in B\phi$. Hence $A\phi\subseteq  B\phi$.

Suppose $x=r\phi, y=s\phi\in A\phi$, some $r,s\in A$. Then we have

$$\begin{align}
xy^{-1}&=(r\phi)(s\phi)^{-1}\\
&=(r\phi)(s^{-1}\phi)\\
&=(rs^{-1})\phi,
\end{align}$$

which is in $A\phi$ since $rs^{-1}\in A\le G$.

Hence $A\phi\le B\phi$.

Now suppose $b\phi\in B\phi$ and $a\phi\in A\phi$. Then we have

$$(b\phi)(a\phi)(b\phi)^{-1}=(b\phi)(a\phi)(b^{-1}\phi)=(bab^{-1})\phi,$$

but $bab^{-1}\in A$ as $A\unlhd B$. Hence $(b\phi)(a\phi)(b\phi)^{-1}\in A\phi$.

Hence $A\phi\unlhd B\phi$.

Comment: Shaun: please abide by the [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|143.1000).

Comment: Its a lot of words used to state the problem, and add "I have no clue".  It should have been closed and deleted as a dupe,  And the other post also closed and deleted.

Comment: But it's not a PSQ, @amWhy; the OP states the problem is from their notes and that they have tried working with abelian groups (to no avail). What is it a duplicate of?

Comment: So: I really tried hard for hours, "to no avail"  is NOT context: What did they try? Explain for us.  Why did it not result in success? Where did you get stuck.   You wouldn't hire anyone who walked in your office saying: $I have had so many occupations, trust my word, I have a lot of experience, please hire me"????

Comment: Please do not post further requests in CURED unless you agree to  be above board.